# Why "dnf groupupdate" packages don't appear when "dnf update"?

Tags: centos, fedora, dnf

```
$ dnf grouplist --installed --verbose
Groupes d’environnements installés :
   Fedora Workstation (workstation-product-environment)
Groupes installés :
   Outils de développement et bibliothèques pour C (c-development)
   Gestion des conteneurs (container-management)
   LibreOffice (libreoffice)
   GNOME (gnome-desktop)
   Polices de caractères (fonts)
   Prise en charge du matériel (hardware-support)

$ sudo dnf groupupdate fonts
Dernière vérification de l’expiration des métadonnées effectuée il y a 3:42:38 le mer. 21 déc. 2022 10:19:59.
Dépendances résolues.
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Paquet                                                      Architecture                    Version                                                   Dépôt                            Taille
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
Installation des paquets du groupe/module:
 abattis-cantarell-vf-fonts                                  noarch                          0.301-8.fc37                                              fedora                           121 k
 google-noto-naskh-arabic-vf-fonts                           noarch                          20201206^1.git0c78c8329-7.fc37                            updates                          107 k
 google-noto-sans-arabic-vf-fonts                            noarch                          20201206^1.git0c78c8329-7.fc37                            updates                          122 k
 google-noto-sans-gurmukhi-vf-fonts                          noarch                          20201206^1.git0c78c8329-7.fc37                            updates                           43 k
 google-noto-sans-math-fonts                                 noarch                          20201206^1.git0c78c8329-7.fc37                            updates                          279 k
 vazirmatn-vf-fonts                                          noarch                          33.003-2.fc37                                             fedora                           149 k
Installation des groupes:
 Fonts
```

<I don't update>

```
$ sudo dnf update
Dernière vérification de l’expiration des métadonnées effectuée il y a 3:44:23 le mer. 21 déc. 2022 10:19:59.
Dépendances résolues.
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Paquet                                                Architecture                     Version                                     Dépôt                                               Taille
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
Installation:
 kernel                                                x86_64                           6.0.13-300.fc37                             updates                                             115 k
 kernel-core                                           x86_64                           6.0.13-300.fc37                             updates                                              48 M
 kernel-modules                                        x86_64                           6.0.13-300.fc37                             updates                                              58 M
 kernel-modules-extra                                  x86_64                           6.0.13-300.fc37                             updates                                             3.3 M
Mise à jour:
 aardvark-dns                                          x86_64                           1.4.0-1.fc37                                updates                                             989 k
 elfutils                                              x86_64                           0.188-3.fc37                                updates                                             529 k
 elfutils-debuginfod-client                            x86_64                           0.188-3.fc37                                updates                                              40 k
 elfutils-default-yama-scope                           noarch                           0.188-3.fc37                                updates                                              15 k
 elfutils-libelf                                       x86_64                           0.188-3.fc37                                updates                                             196 k
 elfutils-libs                                         x86_64                           0.188-3.fc37                                updates                                             257 k
 gnome-online-accounts                                 x86_64                           3.46.0-3.fc37                               updates                                             496 k
 hadolint                                              x86_64                           2.8.0-8.fc37                                updates                                             4.0 M
 libbsd                                                x86_64                           0.11.7-2.fc37                               updates                                             112 k
 libshumate                                            x86_64                           1.0.3-1.fc37                                updates                                             119 k
 megasync                                              x86_64                           4.7.3.0-2.fc37                              rpmfusion-nonfree-updates                           8.8 M
 mesa-dri-drivers                                      x86_64                           22.3.1-1.fc37                               updates                                              17 M
 mesa-filesystem                                       x86_64                           22.3.1-1.fc37                               updates                                              18 k
 mesa-libEGL                                           x86_64                           22.3.1-1.fc37                               updates                                             131 k
 mesa-libGL                                            x86_64                           22.3.1-1.fc37                               updates                                             176 k
 mesa-libgbm                                           x86_64                           22.3.1-1.fc37                               updates                                              45 k
 mesa-libglapi                                         x86_64                           22.3.1-1.fc37                               updates                                              57 k
 mesa-libxatracker                                     x86_64                           22.3.1-1.fc37                               updates                                             2.1 M
 mesa-va-drivers                                       x86_64                           22.3.1-1.fc37                               updates                                             3.4 M
 mesa-vulkan-drivers                                   x86_64                           22.3.1-1.fc37                               updates                                             7.5 M
 netavark                                              x86_64                           1.4.0-1.fc37                                updates                                             1.8 M
 perl-DateTime-TimeZone                                noarch                           2.57-1.fc37                                 updates                                             394 k
 pipewire-codec-aptx                                   x86_64                           0.3.63-1.fc37                               rpmfusion-free-updates                               25 k
 xorg-x11-server-Xorg                                  x86_64                           1.20.14-12.fc37                             updates                                             1.5 M
 xorg-x11-server-common                                x86_64                           1.20.14-12.fc37                             updates                                              34 k
Installation des dépendances:
 libmd                                                 x86_64                           1.0.4-2.fc37                                fedora                                               39 k
Suppression:
 kernel                                                x86_64                           6.0.8-200.fc36                              @updates                                              0
 kernel-core                                           x86_64                           6.0.8-200.fc36                              @updates                                             97 M
 kernel-modules                                        x86_64                           6.0.8-200.fc36                              @updates                                             60 M
 kernel-modules-extra                                  x86_64                           6.0.8-200.fc36                              @updates                                            3.4 M
```

**Why don't I see google-noto fonts updates from the group fonts when I `dnf update` ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual:

```
dnf [options] group upgrade <group-spec>...
      Upgrades the packages from the group and upgrades the group itself. The latter
      comprises of installing packages that were added to the group by the distribution
      and removing packages that got removed from the group as far as they were not
      installed explicitly by the user.
```

Mind the part which says: *"comprises of **installing** packages that **were added** to the group by the distribution"*.

On the other hand `dnf update` **only** updates the existing packages.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I see which package of the group were installed when I ran "dnf group install" and which package are new today ? And how do you automatically update groups when issuing a "dnf update" ? Or how can I upgrade all groups I've already installed ?

Comment: Please ask a new question(s) for that.

Comment: A command to upgrade all installed groups: `dnf -q group list --installed | tail -n +2 | while read group; do dnf group upgrade "$group"; done` - must be run under root, or add `sudo` before each `dnf`

Comment: Here's a one-liner: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729229/260833