# Lines with spaces in the input, use them quoted for a command

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm lazy today so I'm looking for a simple solution for this task. Input has multiple lines with spaces. A command must be run with lines put in quotes. I'm pretty sure it's been asked here many times, so please point me in the direction of a solution.

Example:

```
Aaa aaa
Bbb bbb
Ccc ccc
```

Need to run `command "Aaa aaa" "Bbb bbb" "Ccc ccc"`.

This is about this question: [Why "dnf groupupdate" packages don't appear when "dnf update"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729212/why-dnf-groupupdate-packages-dont-appear-when-dnf-update)

I've offered:

```bash
# the first line is informational and redundant, thus tail
# each group is in a separate line
dnf -q group list --installed | tail -n +2 | while read group; do dnf group upgrade "$group"; done
```

but it will run `dnf upgrade` for each group separately which will take a little bit more time than upgrading all groups at once.

Comment: use a `while`/`read` loop, and attach the read lines to an array, then call with said array?

Comment: use GNU `parallel`?

Comment: That's a lot of code, @MarcusMüller I'm looking for something dead simple :-) or maybe not. I need to check it out.

Comment: `parallel` would be a single line of invoking `parallel`;)

Comment: You mean something like `dnf group upgrade "$(dnf -q group list --installed | tail -n +2 | perl -ne 'chomp; print "\"$_\" "')"`?

Comment: @terdon ohh, cute :)

Comment: This will work, now I want something in bash :-) There's an extra issue of `while` spawning a new shell so that needs to be reversed to keep the array.

Answer (score 3):

Quotes are parts of the syntax of some programming languages such as C, perl or sh.

You don't want to put quotes around those lines, you want the contents of those lines (without the line delimiters) to be passed as separate arguments to your command, rather than building code in the syntax of some programming language such as sh / perl that includes some quoting operators for it to be later interpreted.

That's what `xargs` is for:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a file.list some-command --
```

Note that `-r`, `-d`, and `-a` are GNU extensions though.

`xargs` may run `some-command` several times to work around the limit on the number of arguments that can be passed in one go.

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly but it works in Bash:

```bash
groups=()
while read -r group; do groups+=$group; done < \
  <(sudo dnf -C -q group list --installed | tail -n +2)
sudo dnf group upgrade "${groups[@]}"
```

Comment: `readarray -t groups < <(dnf bla-bla...); dnf group upgrade "${groups[@]}"`

Comment: Bash somehow automatically removes preceding and ending spaces, while your command doesn't. Not sure it will work.

Comment: "Bash somehow automatically removes preceding and ending spaces" -- the `read` command does that: it trims leading and trailing characters that appear in $IFS (default space, tab, newline). To read a line absolutely verbatim, we temporarily set IFS to an empty string: `IFS= read -r line`

Comment: I would have gone with `readarray` too, FWIW

Comment: Well, there was no mention in your Q that you need leading & trailing spaces removed. A quick search tells me this `dnf` thing is a "dandified" YUM ... looks like its output is designed for human consumption... so in essence this is like trying to parse `ls` output... There has to be another way to do this reliably (like querying the rpm database) but I stopped using RPM-based distros some 15 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with [Stéphane Chazelas' variant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729232/116858) if I had GNU `xargs`.  But since I do not have GNU `xargs` on my primary systems, I would make sure that the lines were quoted before feeding them to `xargs`:

```bash
$ sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' file | xargs printf '<%s>\n'
<Aaa aaa>
<Bbb bbb>
<Ccc ccc>
```

This assumes that there is no other double-quote quoting in the input.  Depending on your `xargs`, this may also execute the utility at least once, no matter whether the input to `xargs` is empty or not (see [If no input is given to xargs, don't let xargs run the utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521595)).